# Introduction to python optimization

Tags: python, optimization

Problem Statement :

Construct a building which will be a pile of n cubes. The cube at the bottom will have a volume of n^3, the cube above will have volume of (n-1)^3 and so on until the top which will have a volume of 1^3.

You are given the total volume m of the building. Being given m can you find the number n of cubes you will have to build?

The parameter of the function findNb (find_nb, find-nb, findNb) will be an integer m and you have to return the integer n such as n^3 + (n-1)^3 + ... + 1^3 = m if such a n exists or -1 if there is no such n.

Below code is correct mathematically and would calculate correct value but would fails when submitted on codewars. The message says if it takes more than 12 seconds on their servers to execute, it requires more optimization. Thank you for your help.

```
def find_nb(m):
# your code
    n = int(m**(1./3.))
    #print (n)
    total_volume = 0
    for i in range (1,n+1):
      #print (i*i*i)
      total_volume+= i*i*i
      #print (total_volume)
      if(total_volume == m):
        #print (i)
        return i
        break
return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use some maths. Typically, the sum of k^3 for k=1 to n is (n(n+1)/2)^2.
So

```
def find_nb(m):
    i=0
    while int((i(i+1)/2)**2) < m:
        i += 1
    if ((i(i+1)/2)^2) == m:
        return(i)
return(-1)
```

This is probably not the best solution, but you should try it, as it enables to avoid a loop.